# How do you undo the changes caused by the TZ environment variable and tzset() function?

Tags: c

I have unit test code with logic that applies to a specific time zone. Ideally the unit test executable would always run with the same behavior, and be isolated from the system time zone settings.

In other words, if the system time is U.S. Central, then the unit test passes, but if Asia/Tokyo (for example), then the unit test fails, and the goal would be for the unit test to always pass.

I know that I can set the `TZ` environment variable with `setenv()` or `putenv()`, then call the `tzset()` function, and this will affect results from `mktime()` and `localtime()` according to a new time zone. And examples of what you can set `TZ` are here:
http://famschmid.net/timezones.html

The general format of `TZ` is described here:
http://famschmid.net/uclinuxtutorial_nios.html#ntp

So the unit test executable can be made to have `mktime()` and `localtime()` behave as though the system were `America/Chicago`, with: `TZ=CST+6CDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0` (DST begins 2nd Sunday of March and ends 1st Sunday of November, with standard offset of UTC-6).

The same code works on both Windows and Linux.

However, the moment you do this in the executable, it affects all `mktime()` and `localtime()` calls throughout the code for the remainder of the execution (not just the specific tests).

My question is how do you *undo* the changes, so other code executing later that uses time.h local time functions, uses the system time settings (for example in timestamps in log messages)?

There are examples on the internet of doing a save/restore of the `TZ` environment variable around the test code. However, what if the `TZ` environment variable is initially blank?

Is there a way to populate the `TZ` variable with whatever is correct for the current system time settings? Or more directly, is there a way to revert any changes brought on by `TZ` and `tzset();`, and go back to how the process was on startup?

If there is no POSIX/ANSI C way to do it, is there any Windows and/or Linux specific API to undo the changes?

Here is a test program. It appears simply setting `TZ` to an empty string and calling `tzset()` undoes the changes on Windows, but not on Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#endif

const char *Europe_Istanbul = "EET-2EEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0";
const char *original_tz;

int set_env(const char *name, const char *value)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    return _putenv_s(name, value == NULL ? "" : value);
#else
    if (value == NULL)
        return unsetenv(name);
    else
        return setenv(name, value, 1);
#endif
}

void log_time(time_t t)
{
    struct tm T;
    char timestamp[128] = "";
    T = *localtime(&t);
    strftime(timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%FT%T%z", &T);
    printf("%s\n", timestamp);
}

int main(void)
{
    time_t current_time = time(NULL);

    /* save TZ */
    original_tz = getenv("TZ");

    printf("TZ=%s\n", original_tz);

    log_time(current_time);

    set_env("TZ", Europe_Istanbul);
    tzset();

    log_time(current_time);

    /* restore TZ */
    set_env("TZ", original_tz);
    tzset();

    log_time(current_time);

    return 0;
}
```

Output on Windows (no TZ):

```
D:\>echo %TZ%
%TZ%

D:\>test_tz
TZ=(null)
2019-11-26T11:16:58-0600
2019-11-26T19:16:58+0200
2019-11-26T11:16:58-0600
```

Output on Windows (with TZ)

```
D:\>set TZ=EST+5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0

D:\>echo %TZ%
EST+5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0

D:\>test_tz
TZ=EST+5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
2019-11-26T12:17:59-0500
2019-11-26T19:17:59+0200
2019-11-26T12:17:59-0500
```

Output on Linux (no TZ):

```
[user@host dir]$ echo $TZ

[user@host dir]$ ./test_tz
TZ=(null)
2019-11-26T11:23:18-0600
2019-11-26T19:23:18+0200
2019-11-26T11:23:18-0600
```

Output on Linux (with TZ):

```
[user@host dir]$ export TZ=EST+5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
[user@host dir]$ echo $TZ
EST+5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
[user@host dir]$ ./test_tz
TZ=EST+5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
2019-11-26T12:25:20-0500
2019-11-26T19:25:20+0200
2019-11-26T12:25:20-0500
```

Comment: You are up against a pretty nasty, fundamental limitation of the traditional C/Unix timezone API.  No, there isn't really a better way other than saving and restoring TZ, and calling `tzset` again.  What you really want are the BSD `tzalloc`, `localtime_rz`, and `mktime_z` functions.

Comment: You could `fork()` to do the test, but that's a bit extreme, and wouldn't work on systems that do not support `fork()`.

Comment: It sounds like your biggest problem with saving and restoring TZ is the possibility that TZ wasn't initially set at all.  I think (but I haven't verified) that setting TZ to "" is tantamount to not having TZ set at all.  Alternatively, under Unix at least, I'm pretty sure there's a way (although it may be deprecated/nonstandard) to reset the entire environment and/or delete/unset an environment variable.

Comment: Can't you `old timezone = getenv()` + `setenv(new timezone)` + do the job + `setenv(old timezone)`? Can TZ be empty?

Comment: You said that setting `TZ` to an empty string undoes the changes on Windows, but I think that is wrong. It attempts to set the time zone to that which the operating system is set to. On Linux, it sets the time zone to UTC.

Comment: @SteveSummit I thought the same, but it apparently works on Windows but not Linux.

Comment: @KamilCuk No, because I don't know what the original time zone was. TZ is blank.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah that's pretty much what I mean exactly by "undo the changes", i.e attempt set to whatever the system settings are.

Comment: TZ is not allowed to be empty https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ . It has the form `:characters` or `std offset dst offset, rule`. `what the original time zone was` - so use `getenv("TZ")` to get it.

Comment: In POSIX, `unsetenv("TZ");` will unset the `TZ` environment variable completely.

Comment: @RichJahn But what if `TZ` was initially set to something non-blank? Setting it to blank will not "undo the changes" in that case.

Comment: @KamilCuk Technically, that's correct (although it is also allowed to be missing entirely), but implementations are forgiving. For example, I don't know any implementations that require the initial colon for the `:characters` form.

Comment: Yes, totally agree, glibc ignores the `:` and parses empty or missing TZ as UTC.

Comment: There is an error in the usage of `putenv` in the above code. It is not allowed to be called with an automatic variable as the string becomes part of the environment without copying. Use `setenv` instead, as it is easier to use and it copies the strings. For example: `old_tz = getenv("TZ");` ... `if (old_tz) setenv("TZ", old_tz, 1); else unsetenv("TZ");`.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment about `putenv`, `setenv`, etc., the string (if any) returned by `getenv` would need to be copied. E.g. `old_tz = getenv("TZ"); if (old_tz) old_tz = strdup(old_tz);`. Otherwise, the contents of `old_tz` would be overwritten by subsequent calls to `getenv`.

Comment: I think the test program I have now is an answer. I didn't realize `TZ` from the environment apparently takes effect immediately on program startup even without calling `tzset();`.